# Export to excel multiple sheet/tab in salesforce apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, excel

I want to Implement export to excel functionality in salesforce apex with Visual force page. I want to export to excel with multiple sheet/tabs. Sheet/tab would be dynamic. There are multiple datatable/grid is available I have to export each data table to different sheet. How can I achieve this?

```
<apex:repeat value="{!MenuRepeat}" var="main">
      <Worksheet ss:Name="{!main.SourceSetupValueType__c}">
          <Table x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1">
              <Column ss:Width="160"/>
              <Column ss:Width="160"/>
              <Column ss:Width="160"/>
             
              <Row>
                  <Cell ss:StyleID="Headers"><Data ss:Type="String">Property Name</Data></Cell>
                  <Cell ss:StyleID="Headers"><Data ss:Type="String">Source Master Source</Data></Cell>
                  <Cell ss:StyleID="Headers"><Data ss:Type="String">Source Value</Data></Cell>
                  
              </Row>
              <apex:repeat value="{!Result}" var="res">
                  <Row>
                      <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">{!res.SourcePropertyName__c}</Data></Cell>
                      <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">{!res.SourceMasterSource__c}</Data></Cell>
                      <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">{!res.SourceSetupValueName__c}</Data></Cell>
                      
                  </Row>
              </apex:repeat>
          </Table>
      </Worksheet>
  </apex:repeat>
```

My Controller code is here:

```
public String xlsHeader
{
    get
    {
    String strHeader = '';
    strHeader += '<?xml version="1.0"?>';
    strHeader += '<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>';
    return strHeader;
    }
}

public List<AH_DS_SetupValue_Mapping__c> getMenuRepeat()
{        
    lstSetupvalueMenu = new List<AH_DS_SetupValue_Mapping__c>();            
    List<AggregateResult> ResultData = new List<AggregateResult>();           
    ResultData = [SELECT Count(Id),SourceSetupValueType__c,ProjectId__c FROM AH_DS_SetupValue_Mapping__c where ProjectId__c =: PropertyNameSelectedValue  Group by SourceSetupValueType__c,ProjectId__c Order by SourceSetupValueType__c ASC];   
               
    for(AggregateResult a : ResultData) {            
        AH_DS_SetupValue_Mapping__c sv = new AH_DS_SetupValue_Mapping__c();
        sv.SourceSetupValueType__c = String.valueOf(a.get('SourceSetupValueType__c'));
        sv.ProjectId__c = String.valueOf(a.get('ProjectId__c')); 
        lstSetupvalueMenu.add(sv);                                                  
    }
    System.debug('lstSetupvalueMenu.size()  ' +lstSetupvalueMenu.size());
    for(Integer j=0; j< lstSetupvalueMenu.size(); j++)
    {
        string strQuery=''  ;
        strQuery = 'SELECT SourceMasterSource__c,SourcePropertyName__c,SourceSetupValueName__c,TargetSetupValueId__c,TargetSetupValueMasterSource__c,TargetSetupValueName__c FROM AH_DS_SetupValue_Mapping__c WHERE ProjectId__c = ' +'\'' + lstSetupvalueMenu[j].ProjectId__c + '\'' + ' AND SourceSetupValueType__c = ' +'\'' + lstSetupvalueMenu[j].SourceSetupValueType__c  + '\'' + ' Order by SourceSetupValueType__c ASC';
        System.debug('strQuery  ' +strQuery);
        Result = Database.query(strQuery); 
    }
                  
    return lstSetupvalueMenu;
}
```

Here,I use two repeater but when I export that data In every sheet it's display last setup value data. It's overwrite data in every sheet.

Comment: What have you done so far? What problem have you encountered?

Comment: This is not something that Salesforce can do natively. sfdcfox [has a good answer on this similar question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/130300/generate-xlsx-file-from-apex) for why that is.

Comment: Can you please look out this code. @MariiaIllarionova